# ASP.NET Web Form crashes after 50 clicks

Tags: asp.net, oracle, connection

I have a webform in ASP.NET in C# and it works fine, but after exactly 50 clicks, it crashes and says ERROR 500.

I read that it could be that I have a connection open and I've checked them all and they are all closed.

Is there something else I'm supposed to be doing?

Could I have too many connections? Even though they all closed after being used.
I would appreciate any help, thanks!

EDIT: Also, forgot to add. When this happens I keep getting this error for about 20 minutes and then just works again.

Comment: Just confirm whether you are saving something in session or viewstate during these clicks. enable and see detailed errors of your web messages, because this is a general message without giving information on what's really happening for security reasons.

Comment: In most cases, a 50 clicks or 64 clicks suggests that the connection pool and you not having closed your database connection in code is the issue/problem. Wrap the sql query and database operations you have in a  "using block" It not so much that you might have left the conneciton open as opposed to disposing of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

We need to investigate this kind of issue at debug and IIS level.

1. Use .net profiler to understand where are high memory and CPU usage and then you can do optimization.
2. At IIS level check worker process CPU and Memory usage and check the IIS log of that moment when CPU usage is high.